# Akeidas Yitzchok: why did Avrohom not prepare to throw Yitzchak's blood on the altar?

Tags: korban, blood, binding-of-isaac

[Beraishis 22 (9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

> They arrived at the place of which God had told him. Abraham built an
> altar there; he laid out the wood; he bound his son Isaac; he laid him
> on the altar, on top of the wood.

Before attempting the slaughter of Yitzchak, Avrohom binds his hands and feet and places him on the altar.
The command in 22(2) is to bring  Yitzchak as a burnt offering.

The normal procedure for a burnt offering is commanded in the beginning of [Vayikro](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.1.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0) and involves the stages of slaughter, sprinkling the blood on the altar, taking the skin off the animal before putting the animal on the altar.

The issue of placing Yitzchak on the altar alive is covered by two commentators.

[The Haemek Dovor](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.9?lang=bi&with=Haamek%20Davar&lang2=en)  says that we do not put a normal korban oloh on the altar alive:

> because the skin of an animal is not sacrificed, which is not the case
> with human skin, as it is true flesh. For that reason it is better to
> place him up alive.

[Rav S R Hirsch](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.9?lang=bi&with=Rav%20Hirsch&lang2=en) says

> It is not the usual way for the sacrifice to be slaughtered on the
> altar. It seems that Abraham wanted to sacrifice his son in such a way
> that after the great thing of him was accomplished, he would have
> nothing more to do, so he wanted to sacrifice his son on the pile of
> wood, so that the flames might consume the body of his child.

What is not mentioned here in 22 (9) is any preparation that Avrohom should have made to collect the blood and put it on the altar. That he knew that the blood had to placed on the altar is evident from [Rashi on 22 (14)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.13?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) where he says on the words IN THE STEAD OF HIS SON

> At every sacrificial act he performed on it he prayed saying, “May it
> be Thy will that this act may be regarded as having been done to my
> son — as though my son is being slain; **as though his blood is being
> sprinkled**; as though his skin were being flayed; as though he is
> being burnt and is being reduced to ashes”

So why did Avrohom not prepare to throw  Yitzchak's blood on the altar?

Comment: See Bereishis Rabbah 56:8. G-d never intended that Avraham actually offered Yitzchak. G-d told Avraham to go up.

Comment: Yes. G-d never intended that Avraham actually offered Yitzchak. But initially Avraham thought that he was to offer him up and he took steps to acheive this (knife, mizbeach, fire). But nothing to do with blood.

Comment: *Zerikas hadam* does not apply with a *bamah*. https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93/8lEmAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%93%D7%9D+%22%D7%A2%D7%9C+%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%94%22&dq=%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%93%D7%9D+%22%D7%A2%D7%9C+%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%94%22&printsec=frontcover

Comment: and presumably semichoh too (which I should have mentioned in the question). Thank you @The GRAPKE